# Setting R working directory relative to R file open in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

How do I set the working directory relative to the path of the R file open inside RStudio?

**How this question is different from the others on this topic:**

- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452086/getting-path-of-an-r-script) The source command is only part of the answer, and I am not using a package. I would like to use default R, not the R script package.
- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672720/r-command-for-setting-working-directory-to-source-file-location) didnt work for me on Win7 x64
- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31433559/what-is-a-fool-proof-way-of-permanently-setting-r-working-directory) I dont want to set it permanently to the same place.

Comment: What is “the open R file”? This isn’t a concept that R supports. However, I’ve had to implement something like this for my package [‹modules›](https://github.com/klmr/modules), and the [solution is quite tricky](https://github.com/klmr/modules/blob/51e12165494257df3c79d7b0babcc4c89c012964/R/module_cache.r#L67-L98). Depending on your use-case, my answer would be: use ‹modules›.

Comment: You mean that when you open a file, R doesnt store the path somewhere? I am trying to get that path.

Comment: “when you open a file” — **how**?

Comment: By clicking the .R script file. In my case it opens by default in RStudio

Comment: Please be explicit! R is a programming language, it has no concept of clicking on a file. So you opening a file in RStudio. That doesn’t open any file in R, it opens it in *RStudio*, that’s very different.

Comment: I always thought of RStudio as a GUI wrapper on top of R, based on your comment I am assuming this is not the case?

Comment: No, this is not the case. RStudio is and IDE that happens to be optimized for R. But you can use many other IDEs, e.g. Eclipse or Emacs. R itself is a language and has no conception of the IDE you run it in.